# Need to get value of the tab in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have list of array passing to a tab. When I select the tab the value of "s" should reflect in controller which I am not able to find the solution.

```
  <div class="widget-body padding-10">
            <ul id="Tabs" class="nav nav-tabs bordered">
              <li ng-repeat="s in services track by $index">
                <a id="s{{$index}}tab" href="#s{{$index}}" data-toggle="tab">
                  <i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-file" ></i> {{s}}
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <div id="TabsContent" class="tab-content padding-10">
              <div class="tab-pane active" id="s{{$index}}" ng-repeat="s in services track by $index">
                <div style="height:500px;width: 100%;">
                  <div id="{{ s }}" style="height:100%;width: 100%" ></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Please help we with this

Answer (score 1):

Add ng-click directive to your li element:

```
  <li ng-repeat="s in services track by $index" ng-click="functionInScope(s)">
        <a id="s{{$index}}tab" href="#s{{$index}}" data-toggle="tab">
          <i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-file" ></i> {{s}}
        </a>
   </li>
```

and from there you can do whatever you like to controller with s value.

Comment: I am getting an error here is the link
https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.14/docs/error/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%2524digest

Comment: except ng-click is there any other directive so that i can get the value of "s"